# Socket.on not being called in mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, mocha.js

I try to test socket.io using mocha, but i have a problem when make a socket call ***on***. I think socket is not connected, because the console log not triggered but the console.log outside the socket call is show. Or it's wrong about how i use the done() method ?

```
const { assert } = require('chai');
const ioServer = require('socket.io');
const ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
const http = require('http');

const socketUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';
const options = {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  'force new connection': true,
};

let server;
let client;
let httpServer;

describe('Socket', () => {
  beforeEach(done => {
    httpServer = http.createServer().listen();
    server = ioServer(httpServer);
    client = ioClient.connect(socketUrl, options);
    server.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log('connected server');
      socket.emit('echo', 'Hello World');
    });
    client.on('echo', message => {
      console.log('connected client');
      console.log(message);
    });
    console.log('test');
    done();
  });

  afterEach(done => {
    server.close();
    client.close();
    done();
  });

  it('It should connect socket', done => {
    client.on('echo', message => {
      assert.equal(message, 'Hello World');
    });
    done();
  });
});
```

Here's the screenshoot cli terminal when running mocha.
[Mocha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zFM2.png)